# Удаление одинаковых значений в json массиве

Tags: php, json

Есть json массив. Требуется в нем удалить одинаковые домены. В массиве в ᅟᅟᅟDisplayUrl есть http://google.ru и http://google.ru/images, пример. Дк вот, это одинаковый домен, удаляем запись. Структуру массива можно посмотреть по адресу в коде. И слэши в массиве другие, тут оставил так, для наглядности:

```
"Results":[{
    "Title":"Заголовок 1",
    "DisplayUrl":"хттп://google.ru",
}, {
    "Title":"Заголовок 2",
    "DisplayUrl":"хттп://google.ru/img",
}, {
    "Title":"Заголовок 3",
    "DisplayUrl":"хттп://stackoverflow.com",
}]
```

На выходе должны получить, а потом я уже почищу ссылки от лишнего, http:// и https://:

```
"Results":[{
        "Title":"Заголовок 1",
        "DisplayUrl":"хттп://google.ru",
    }, {
        "Title":"Заголовок 3",
        "DisplayUrl":"хттп://stackoverflow.com",
    }]
```

Сам код страницы.

```
        foreach($decode['SearchResponse']['Web']['Results'] as $res) { // foreach loop, to loop through each array value (result) as $res

        $res['Description']=preg_replace("/($testi)/i","<strong>\\1</strong>",$res['Description']);
        $res['Title']=preg_replace("/($testi)/i","<strong>\\1</strong>",$res['Title']);

        $input = $res['DisplayUrl'];
        $input = trim($input, '/');

        if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $input)) {
            $input = 'http://' . $input;
        }

        $urlParts = parse_url($input);

        $domain = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $urlParts['host']);

        echo $domain;
        echo "<br>";
        }
        ?>
```

Пытался так, но хттп://google.ru и хттп://google.ru/img - не одинаковые записи, не вышло:

```
$decode = json_decode($get, TRUE);
$decodeunique = array();
$exists    = array();

foreach($decode['SearchResponse']['Web']['Results'] as $res) { // foreach loop, to loop through each array value (result) as $res

    if( !in_array( $res['Url'], $exists )) {
            $decodeunique[] = $res;
            $exists[]    = $res['Url'];
        }
    echo json_encode( $decodeunique );
}
```

Еще как видно в первом коде, там из домена удаляется все лишнее, по выводу получаем google.ru. Думал там, удалять дубликаты, но тогда испортится структура массива, и на выходе в сниппете в DisplayUrl будет просто пусто.

Comment: Какие символы могут быть в строке? Только строчные и заглавные английские буквы?

Comment: Только строчные.

Comment: А как вы тогда предполагаете выделять подстроки из этой строки? Есть хоть какие-нибудь критерии?

Comment: Но <br>-ом же выводится списком?

Comment: Если вывести строку, которую вы указали в вопросе, то будет `'IvanFeduorGalinaRomaIvanGalina'`.

Comment: Если добавить `echo "<br>";` то будет столбиком.

Comment: Dmitriy, оставьте свои контакты.

Comment: Пока вы четко не сформулируете вопрос -- вряд ли кто-то сможет на него ответить.

Comment: Опишите вашу задачу шире. Откуда вы берете исходную строку и зачем оттуда нужно убирать дубликаты?

Comment: Поправил запрос.